# What does the "OI" symbol mean on a tuning orb?

Tags: new-world

There is a blue circular symbol on my Amrine Tuning Orb that has the letters "OI" in it.  This symbol is only present when the orb is in my storage and not my inventory.  I do appear to currently have a mission that requires using it, however I would expect it to have the yellow diamond symbol on it like the Starstone Tuning Orb next to it:

[image: Orbs]

What does the "OI" symbol mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s a placeholder quest item. Restarting the game can possibly get rid of it.

Comment: So it's a bug is what you're saying essentially?

Comment: Yes It’s a bug.

Comment: Seems like it was in fact some sort of bug.  It's gone now after starting the game up today.